# How to get multiselected files from input to c# object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to get all files that are selected in input file to c# object, but it select only one file from mutiselected files to display in text box.

Input file to select multiple files:

```
<input type="file" name="File2" id="File2" accept="image/*" multiple/>
```

Input text to display all selected files:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DocumentName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @id = "documentName", @class = "form-control" } })
```

Model:

```
 [Display(Name = "DocumentName", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Resources))]
        public override string DocumentName
        {
            get { return base.DocumentName; }
            set { base.DocumentName = value; }
        }
```

What changes are required in my code, to resolve it?

Comment: You could try jquery for this display selected files.. if able to do with jquery means i will share how to do it.

Comment: Please explain how?

Comment: Can you make changes in my code, to achieve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please Add this in your script. It will works when selecting files on upload i.e OnChange Functionality. Please Try it and Let me know.

```
 $("document").ready(function(){
$("#File2").change(function() {
    var files = $(this)[0].files;
for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    $("#documentName").val(files[i].name);
}    });});
```